# Proof regarding double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

We need to prove that:
$$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{f'(y)dydx}{\sqrt{(a-x)(x-y)}}=\pi(f(a)-f(0))$$
where, $a$ is a positive constant.

I couldn't see anything by looking at the LHS so I switched the order of integration as:
$$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{f'(y)dydx}{\sqrt{(a-x)(x-y)}}=\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{f'(y)dxdy}{\sqrt{(a-x)(x-y)}}$$

After calculating the first integral I was left with:
$$\int_{0}^{a}(\frac{-\pi}{2}+\arcsin(\frac{a+y}{a-y}))f'(y)dy$$
but I can't figure out how to calculate the second part of this integral to get the result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the easiest way is to change the order of integration:
$J(a)=\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{f'(y)dydx}{\sqrt{(a-x)(x-y)}}=\int_{0}^{a}f'(y)dy\int_{y}^{a}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a-x)(x-y)}}$

Then the integral type $I(a,b)=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}}$ ($b>a$) after the change $x=(b-a)t+a$ becomes

$I(a,b)=(b-a)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(b-a)t}\sqrt{(b-a)(1-t)}}=B(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2})=\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{2})=\pi$

$J(a)=\pi\int_{0}^{a}f'(y)dy=\pi(f(a)-f(0))$